# CakePHP $this Syntax

Tags: php, cakephp

I've been trying to learn CakePhp for a while now but I still can't get alot of stuff. I've been reading a lot and watching videos. I just want to ask a very simple question.

I've been trying to mess with the bookmarks tutorial and i'm watching a video. In the video he baked a component called Validate. In the cmd he typed

```
bin/cake/bake component Validate
```

Then a ValidateComponent.php appeared in the component folder in the controller. Now he used the ValidateComponent.php by going to the BookmarksController and adding to the initialize method

```
$this->loadComponent('Validate');
```

I just want to ask where did the word validate come from? shouldn't it be ValidateComponent? and where does he get the loadComponent from? I've seen him using `$this->method();` or `$this->method('string', [array]);` I just want to know how the syntax works and what each word means. Sorry for the long explanation. I'm really trying to learn and i'm really confused. thank you very much.

ValidateComponent.php

```
    <?php
namespace App\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;
use Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry;

/**
 * Validate component
 */
 class ValidateComponent extends Component
{

/**
 * Default configuration.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_defaultConfig = [];

public function validLimit($limit, $ default)
{
    if (is_numeric($limit)){
    return $limit;
}
return $default;
}

}
```

part of BookmarksController.php

```
 public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('Validate');

}
```

I can't seem to find where he got the word 'Validate'

Comment: You want to read the OOP chapter of the php language. Learn the basics of the language before trying to use a framework. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php Also the framework comes with build in validation mechanisms of different kinds. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html Further a component is the wrong place for validation. Read about MVC and design patterns. I recommend you to do the blog tutorial in the documentation instead of jumping blindly into unknown waters.

Comment: @burzum Thanks for these materials! I will surely use it! Sorry if i'm blindly jumping here. I understood most of the basics I've read, it's just that I lack materials to read because I don't know where to look and what to look for and you gave me one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every controller in your application extends a base Controller `Controller` or `AppController` which extends `Controller`

`Controller` have bunch of methods, One of these methods is the `loadComponent()` ([See Source](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/source-class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_loadComponent))

```
public function loadComponent($name, array $config = [])
     {
         list(, $prop) = pluginSplit($name);
         $this->{$prop} = $this->components()->load($name, $config);
     }
```

**Why Validate instead of ValidateComponent?**

Short answer: **suffix**.

[See predefined suffix in App class](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-App.html#107)

CakePHP uses suffix to load classes, When you hit `loadComponent()` You go to [ComponentRegistery](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/source-class-Cake.Controller.ComponentRegistry.html#28) class to Register the component, ComponentRegistery will call App class to load class. [__loadClass()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-App.html#__loadClass)

Almost everything in CakePHP has a suffix, In your case ValidateComponent has the `Component` suffix.

`return App::className($class, 'Controller/Component', 'Component');` ([Source](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.Controller.ComponentRegistry.html#73))

I hope this will make more sense to you

Comment: Now this makes sense. So it means that Validate and ValidateComponent are the same right?

Comment: Yes, Component is a ```keyword``` or in our case we call it ```suffix```

Answer (score 1):

$this isn't specifically anything to-do with cake but part of PHP itself. In object oriented context $this refers simply to the current class.

$this->something refers to an object within the current scope. This could be within the current class or from an extends or use.

$this->something(); refers similarly to a method or function within the current scope.

If are using an IDE such as netbeans you can usually click through these references to see the object they refer to so for example if you do in fact use Netbeans you could ctrl-click on  $this->loadComponent('Validate'); to see the actual function it refers to.

Regarding where does 'Validate' come from, it's a string you are passing to that object. On the other end it will be used in the function, probably in a switch or if statement to return something.

Eg:

```
Public function loadComponent($type){
    If($type == 'Validation'){
     //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. That's my problem I want to know where "Validate" came from. I'm using xampp. But thanks!

Comment: Xampp isn't an ide it's a piece of software which installs Apache and MySQL for you. An Ide is what you do your coding in.

Comment: I mean I'm just using notepad++. but hey, Thanks! at least i learned that I can use netbeans to look for stuff. :)

Comment: I strongly recommend netbeans over notepad++, sure it's got a reputation for being overly bloated but as long as your PC is OK, it doesn't matter. It'll make your life much much simpler. Also I recommend learning non MVC PHP before investing too much time in cakephp. I tried like you to learn an MVC first (symfony2) and all it did was hinder me. Now I know what it's all about. symfoby is easy. Just learn oo PHP first.